# InnerBlocks with allowedBlocks not working with acf_register_block

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, block-editor

I using the InnerBlocks tag to allow for nested blocks, within my custom block. I am trying to use the 'allowedBlocks' argument to restrict the blocks allowed to only specific ones. However, if I put anything inside the InnerBlocks tag, the block does not load and just spins.

I am using acf_register_block for my block registry, as what we are doing heavily ties in with ACF.
I have enabled `'__experimental_jsx' => true`  in all the blocks I am working with.

This works

```
<div>
    <InnerBlocks />
</div>
```

This does not work

```
<div>
    <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks={ 'acf/orange-carousel' } />
</div>
```

It also doesn't work if I pass an array instead of a string for the allowed blocks.

I am using ACF Pro Beta 5.9

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A late reply but I thought I would include a snippet that worked for me.

Update `$allowed_inner_blocks` with your own "block_types" and place the following code inside the parent block template;

```
<?php $allowed_inner_blocks = ['acf/logos']; ?>
<InnerBlocks allowedBlocks="<?php echo esc_attr(wp_json_encode($allowed_inner_blocks)); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `acf` the correct namespace? if so, this should work in your edit function.

```
const ALLOWED_BLOCKS = [
    'acf/orange-carousel',
]

return (
    <div className={className}>
        <InnerBlocks
            allowedBlocks={ ALLOWED_BLOCKS }
        />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Yea it should be, that's what the block is registered as. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "edit function"? Keep in mind I am using ACF to register these blocks. acf_register_block

Comment: Sorry i missed that. My thought process on this was to use @wordpress/create-block and write a new block, then call your acf block using InnerBlocks there.

Comment: Interesting, Il give it a try